# Can you capture an image from the webcam on an iphone in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, iphone

Basically just looking to see if you can capture an image from the webcam in javascript?   I know you can capture the GPS position in an iphone in javascript so I'd figure there might also be extensions to do images as well.

ideally doing this in a cross platform way would be great.   Basically it would mean we could develop a web app instead of a custom app.   (if it requires a custom app, then unlikely to support the iphone as its too much of a diversion from our normal development equation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is (still*) no.

You can do this in Flash or, god help us, in an Applet.  But if you do the later, you'll get fat, have no friends, and many puppies will die.

* This has already been asked before, but I can't find the thread.

Comment: thanks, best thing I could find was "PhoneGap".  Close, but not quite good enough!